# How to send file information along with the file?

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a server and client file transfer module and I wanted to know If it is possible to send the file info along with file itself.Particularly I need file names and folder structure of the file on server sent to the client.
Ex. if I have c:\abc\efg\a.txt on server I want .\abc\efg\a.txt on client.

this is the code I'm using :

Server Side File Send:

```
    Socket clientSocket=new Socket("Some IP",12345);

    OutputStream out=clientSocket.getOutputStream();

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
    int x=0;
    byte[] b = new byte[4194304];
    while(true){
        x=fis.read(b);
        if(x==-1)break;
        out.write(b);
   }
    out.close();
```

Client Listener:

```
try {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(12345);
        while(true){
            final Socket client = ss.accept();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("rec.txt");
                        int x=0;
                        byte[] b = new byte[4194304];
                        while(true){
                            x=in.read(b);
                            if(x==-1)break;
                            fos.write(b);
                        }
                        fos.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: Of course it is possible but you need to create a more sophisticated protocol for it. Or you can just use one of the many services that already do similar things like HTTP or FTP.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for some native support,I'm aware of all those choices but they are my last options.

Comment: There is no such native support. Unless you use a network filesystem, of course, but this is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the file path then the file name, use a 64 byte buffer to do that, once you get the path and name you read the file contents.

For example:

```
   // Server
   try
   {
       Socket clientSocket=new Socket("Some IP",12345);
       OutputStream out=clientSocket.getOutputStream();
       FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
       byte[] info = new byte[64];
       int len = file.getPath().length();
       info = file.getPath().getBytes();
       for (int i=len; i < 64; i++) info[i]=0x00;
       out.write(info, 0, 64);
       len = file.getName().length();
       info = file.getName().getBytes();
       for (int i=len; i < 64; i++) info[i]=0x00;
       out.write(info, 0, 64);

       int x;
       byte[] b = new byte[4194304];
       while((x=fis.read(b)) > 0)
       {
         out.write(b, 0, x);
       }
      out.close();
      fis.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // Client
  try
  {
      InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("rec.txt");
      byte[] path = new byte[64];
      in.read(path, 0, 64);
      byte[] name = new byte[64];
      in.read(name, 0, 64);

      int x=0;
      byte[] b = new byte[4194304];
      while((x = in.read(b)) > 0)
      {
          fos.write(b, 0, x);
      }
      fos.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Send a header first with all information you need, then a separator (e.g. 0) then the file content. Server side reads the header till the separator then the content.

Comment: This will also require that you send the length of the header/content first.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before. I used DataOutputStream at the server and DataInputStream at the client.

I used  this protocol:
1. send the file name .writeUTF(fileName);
2. send the file size .writeLong(fileSize);
3. send the file .writeBytes(byteArray); // this is done inside a for loop since file size can be too big to be put into memory at once. Both the server and client size will use fileSize to determine when to stop.

The client side will use the same protocol but instead of "write", it will be "read".

Answer (score 0):

Zip
**1.** file
**2.** Information about file
Send it )