# keeping the file name after file transfer

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I'm currently working on a p2p file transfer via socket on java, and I've managed to get the source file(image,pdf,txt,etc) sent to some other directory on localhost. But my problem is if there is any way to keep the file name of the copy same with the original file name after the transfer without hardcoding (I'm using argument line to get the source file path, assign the port to connect to, the IP of the target connection, and the output path)

Comment: How are you copying the file without getting the name in the first place? If you have the name to select the file to copy (I'm assuming this is what you are doing) couldn't you just name the new file with the name of the old?

Comment: I'm getting the file name in the server part of my program(as you've said it's in the first place and it's the only argument for the server part) and handling the rest in the client part, and your question is my actual question, I'm exactly asking how to import the file name from argument line and assign it to copied file's name

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks for the clarification. I tend to get lost trying to understand questions sometimes.

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444651/how-to-send-file-information-along-with-the-file/17445333#17445333). In that question the transfer was from server to client, but the example applies as well.

Comment: booleanCube sometimes you think that you clarified what you want to express, but it seems it's not enough in the practical way, and since I'm new to network programming I try to get used to its terminology which may cause such complications above. 

ja_mesa that'd been quite helpful thank you(although I've searched a lot about this problem seems I've missed that question)

Answer (score 0):

You have to sent it through the socket connection.
I see two solution:

First solution: send it through a new connection.

- Open the connection, send the file name, close it.
- Open the connection, send the file data, close it.
- Save the file with the name and data received.

Second solution: send the name through the same connection.

- Open the connection, send the file name with a special final byte. On the client side read the bytes until you find the special byte.
- Still in the client side continue to read the bytes and save it in the new file.